# I am uploading a CSV file on JSP page with Spring security but on uploading it is showing "Unauthorised access page error 403 page"

Tags: spring, file, file-upload, spring-security

My spring security configuration is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <debug/>

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" >
        <!--        RESOURCES -->

        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/login/login.jsp" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/login*" access="permitAll" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/user*" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/new.version**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/version**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','OPERATIONS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/ver.htm?method=**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','OPERATIONS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/rep.htm?method=**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','OPERATIONS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/upload.htm?method=**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','OPERATIONS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/rep**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','OPERATIONS')" />      
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/upload**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','OPERATIONS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/image/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/include/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" /> -->



        <custom-filter ref="requestParamEncodingFilter" after="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"/>

        <form-login
            login-page="/pages/login/login.jsp" 
            default-target-url="/login.htm?method=login" 
            username-parameter="j_username" 
            password-parameter="j_password" 
            authentication-failure-url="/pages/login/login.jsp?login_error=1"
        />

        <logout logout-success-url="/pages/login/login.jsp" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />

        <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" invalid-session-url="/pages/login/login.jsp" />

        <csrf/> //csrf is enabled here

        <headers>
            <cache-control/>
            <xss-protection/>
            <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        </headers>

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
            <beans:bean class="com.test.component.security.MyInterceptor"/>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <beans:bean class="com.test.component.security.RequestParamEncodingFilter" id="requestParamEncodingFilter"/>
```

I am uploading a CSV file on JSP page and I have used Spring security but on uploading it is showing Unauthorised access page error 403 page when my csrf tag is enabled in spring security configuration. If I disable it my file is successfully uploaded.

Comment: <csrf/> put this tag as first tag inside http tag and check

Answer (score 0):

No need to put csrf tag

Since it is enabled by default if you are using spring 4

As of Spring Security 4.0, CSRF protection is enabled by default with XML configuration.

Check the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure).

for spring 3  check [link](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/#timeouts)

Comment: I am using spring security 3.x in my application and i want it in my application but on upload it is giving me 403 error. Following is my jsp code snippet

Comment: <form name="uploadKPIForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
   <div id="circleFieldDiv" style="margin-left: 33%;">
    <label id="searchFieldLable" style="width: 133px;"> Upload KPI  :</label>
    <!-- <label for="file"> <span class="btn">Upload csv</span></label>  -->
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".csv" /><br><br>
          <input type="button" value="Upload" style="margin-left: 15%; width:96px;" onclick="checkCircleCode()" />
 </div>
</form>

Comment: use  <form:form> example - https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-tags-1.html  . Form tag will automatically add csrf fields required

Comment: See reference guide which explains how to handle csfr and file uploads. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-multipart

Comment: you can enable spring debug log and check what exactly is happening.. If you are already authorize then error should not come. This means the when to uploading role which is assigned is anonymous due to which you are getting 403.

Comment: you can also try reordering your intercept-url  tags with access="permitAll"  as first  , then  access="isAuthenticated()"  and then finally access=hasAnyRole one. I think last intercept-url  tag is creating problem here.